# How to restrict to make a build of react project if version is not changed/upgraded in package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to enable production-level restriction in building to **react** application. I want that if I do not change the version of **react** application it should give me an error during the build process with the error message "Change the react version in Package.json file". How do I accomplish this strategy

Answer (score 0):

Call the global [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) object's [exit](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) method

> Node.js will normally exit with a 0 status code when no more async operations are pending. The following status codes are used in other cases:
>
> 1 Uncaught Fatal Exception: There was an uncaught exception, and it was not handled by a domain or an 'uncaughtException' event handler.

For more information about exit codes you can take a look at [process_exit_codes](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes)

Note: I did not tried to stop a build but you can try the following:

```js
const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

console.log(REACT_VERSION)

if(REACT_VERSION <= "16.6.3"){
  console.log("Change the react version in Package.json file, the current version is smaller than the lastes available!")
  process.exit(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```